Does Blocking Images for Specific Countries Affect My Website’s SEO?
I'm using Bunny.net to host my images, and it offers a country-blocking feature. Since my website is targeted only to a specific country, I'm considering blocking access to my images from all other countries.
Why block other countries?
My website is heavily image-focused, and each request consumes a significant amount of bandwidth.
Question:
Will blocking access to image resources for certain countries negatively impact my SEO? Note that only the images are blocked—my website remains accessible in other countries, but users will see a 403 error for the images.

LackFos!
If you block image loading, search bots from non-target countries will just "catch" 403 errors when crawling your pages.
This could lead to higher bounce rates, and the time spent on the site might drop as well. BUT overall, it might work for local SEO in one country.
However, I’d first try using WebP (if possible, of course) and enable lazy load.
Also, a quick follow-up question: are you using Bunny.net purely as storage or as a CDN as well? I saw the tag, but the context of the question isn’t super clear.
To summarize: this might work for local SEO in one country. But keep in mind, people use VPNs and proxies.

It used for both storage and cdn, quick question does bounce rate affect SEO aswell?

Yes, it does, and directly
